# react-big-scheduler - Redux and prototypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm looking to use [react-big-scheduler](https://github.com/StephenChou1017/react-big-scheduler) alongside Redux for a task scheduling app I'm creating, but I have come up against an issue.

RBS (react-big-scheduler) works by creating a new `ScheduleData` object first, and then from that point onwards, using prototypes on that object to change views/modify data etc. A new `ScheduleData` object is created as such...

```js
// Create a scheduleData object
const myScheduleData = new SchedulerData(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'), ViewTypes.month, false, false);
```

That `ScheduleData` object is then passed to the RBS React component. To perform operations, prototype functions on the created `myScheduleData` object are then called, either by my code, or internally in the RBS library, for example, `myScheduleData.prev()`, `myScheduleData.setEvents(events)`, `myScheduleData.updateEventStart(data)` and so on.

The issue is that when the `myScheduleData` is passed to the Redux store, all those prototype functions that it contains are removed, leaving just the data. That object is then passed back again to the RBS component, where it errors as it cannot call the prototype functions it expects to exist on the object.

I realise that storing prototypes in a store is considered an anti-pattern, but this library expects them to exist, I think I need to "redecorate" them back onto the returned data from the store, but unsure how to go about this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest making a stateful component and only relay important information as actions to store in redux store.

Comment: Thanks @HMR, so are you saying, manage the RBS's own "schedulerData" viewModel object in local component state, and have that state updated based on updates from Redux store? Another question, where is best to call the (for example) `schedulerData.setEvents(events)` method to set the Redux store data into the RBS component? In on render, a redux selector, getderivedstatefromprops or somewhere else? Thanks again